# Taking electronic equipment to India from USA

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, import-taxes

I am planning to take a digital oscilloscope from USA to India which I brought on ebay for about USD 500. The usual cost of the scope can be couple of 1000 dollars. Can anyone advise what will the implications and complications at Indian customs during entry. This is not an item which individuals usually bring along with, so I don't have any idea.

As per customs rules which I read, for people who are in USA for long term can take tools and equipment's worth INR 75,000 but those are rules and fact is arguing at customs is like banging your head against huge rock. so if anybody has any experience please share. I will be entering at Bangalore.

Comment: http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf

Comment: @raj - How did it go for you? Did you put forth any documentation showing it was an item of personal/ professional use that is not be resold

Answer (score 2):

A digital oscilloscope would be considered an item of professional use and is specific enough to not be repurposed or sold in India. You wouldn't be required to declare it while coming into the country.

I'm an Electrical Engineer too and I agree this is a device which is fairly uncommon for travellers, I doubt you'll have issues at customs with it though.